# React Native - Authorization header not working in WebView component on iOS?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to set up a WebView to essentially hit a QA server configured with Apache authorization when my application is running in development mode. According to the React Native documentation, I'm able to pass headers as a prop to a WebView component like this:

```
<WebView source={{uri: "http://example.com", headers: {Authorization: "Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ="}}}/>
```

When I run this on Android with the proper values, I am granted access to the page as expected. On iOS, however, I simply receive a blank screen.

Am I missing something here or is this a bug in React Native? In the latter case, does anybody know of a simple workaround for this scenario?

Comment: Are you using http or https? iOS might not allow http unless you change the `Allow Arbitrary Loads` settings in xcode

Comment: @MattAft Yes. Sorry, forgot to mention that. I've already enabled that. The app will render a warning if you don't set it, so I can confirm that is not the issue.

Comment: This is open bug. Link to it with possible solution: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/18#issuecomment-420232902